# What is the fastest way to iterate over a large list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, iterable

I have looked at question which ask how to iterate over a list of lists, however when the lists get large, time becomes a factor and the question I have seen do not address the efficacy.
I use this method for iteration:

```
[do_something(inner_list) for inner_list in list_of_lists]
```

however I am don't know if this is the quickest way and could not find any StackOverflow question which compare cases and suggest the most efficient way to iterate.

Could anyone say what the fastest way is and why?